# How to change Table of Contents docking position in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table-of-contents

How do I change the Table of Contents window docking position to where it is in this picture?

[image]

I want to change it to a vertical position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that the Table of Contents window is pinned
2. Left-click on the top bar of the Table of Contents window and drag it until the cursor is positioned over the top center blue target where the black "arrow" below is pointing
   [image]
3. You should see the blue box change to show where it is ready to dock
4. Release your left-click

Comment: The trick is making sure it's pinned or it wont let you drag it. Personally I put it on another monitor... I like ArcMap to have the *whole* screen.